# app compiles and works with no frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

So I have a big project (Let's call it A), and some guys with app B wanted to put part of my app in their app, so I created a framework to be added to their app. The steps of creating it were cleaning the code of my app leaving only what's related to what they want, Creating a framework from that, Creating an example app that uses the framework to debug and see that everything works. Until now in terms of frameworks what I did was that I just added to my Example App all the frameworks from my app (A).

Now I came to the point of cleaning out things and leftovers from the frameworks and the Example App, before I send it to B app guys. So I started to delete frameworks from my example app one by one, each time building and running on my device, and every time everything worked perfect. Every 2-3 frameworks I stopped to do deep build-clean, and deleted the app from my iphone, and still everything works. I ended up deleting specific framework that I specifically imported in one of my A app framework classes, still works. My last resort was to delete both UIKit AND Foundation frameworks. Still works perfectly. I did deep clean, uninstall from my iPhone, deleted the DerivedData folder contents, and restarted the computer, and everything still compiles, builds and works.
The only problem I started getting was that my Localytics session gave NSLogs about that the AdSupport framework is missing and that could harm the tracking... still no crash.

As far as I know i'm compiling the framework of my A app without any frameworks in it (Is it even possible to compile frameworks inside a framework?). My framework is built with this wonderful git: [iOS Universal Framework Mk 8](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) (i'm creating a real framework not a fake one).

I basically care about all this because I do want to check out which of the frameworks are useless and can be deleted, and my project is too big to go over and check if and who is using any of the frameworks.

I'm using `Xcode 5.0.1, ios7 SDK, iphone5c`.
I did made sure all the frameworks I have deleted didn't stay in the `Link binary with Libraries` section...

These are the frameworks I have deleted from my Example App project:
`CoreGraphics` `CFNetwork` `SystemConfiguration` `MobileCoreServices` `QuartzCore` `CoreData` `StoreKit` `AdSupport` ( <-The only one I got any response to getting red of) `AVFoundation` `CoreText` `XCTest` `UIKit` `Foundation`

Thanks ahead for any help or idea (:

Comment: Check for includepaths for your library in Build Settings / Search Patchs sections

Comment: I'd imagine that since you're creating a library (.so) and not a full binary you don't actually hit the linking stage. Anyone who uses your library in a full program will need to link with all the libs your code needs.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I just had the same problem and thought my answer could help someone else.

Somehow the TestFlight library I was using had all the required symbols within it.  Removing libTestflight.a from my link step forced me to link UIKit/CoreGraphics again.

Answer (score 0):

The process of going from code to binary with C is a multi-step one. Preprocess, compile, link, load.

1. Source (.c/.m) is preprocessed into a .i file (removes comments, evaluates macros, etc.).
2. Preprocessed code (.i) is lexed, parsed, and compiled into assembly (.s).
3. Assembly (.s) is compiled into machine code in an object or library file (.o/.so/.a).
4. Object files (.o/.a) are linked into a single binary.
5. At runtime, the system figures out which shared libraries (.so) the executable needs and loads them.

As you are building a library, your compilation stops after step 3, so you don't need to actually have the library binaries, you just need the header files to declare the functions (and any typedefs, structs, macros, etc.). The person using your library, however, will go through steps 4 and 5, and so will  need the library binaries.

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following you... After I have created my framework, I created a new project from scratch that uses this framework. Than I deleted all those frameworks that I mentioned in my Q from that example project and everything still worked (Except to sources that were `.dylib` and not `.framework` => `libz.dylib, libsqlite3.dylib`: those 2 did cause a build error). Why would it be different for my customer (the B app guys) who add my framework to existing app instead of creating new project and add my framework?

Comment: If you have an empty app, the app isn't using any of the calls in your library, so the linker probably doesn't even link it. Try adding a call to one of your library functions, preferably one that will need a library you removed.

Comment: The app isn't empty now, I have created an Example App from scratch that uses all of the library methods to make sure they all work, I also called and opened screens that definitely use library that I have deleted. Also the app itself, even without the framework that I built, imports the `Foundation.framework` and `UIKit.framework` in it's `.pch` and the fact those are not exist in the project doesn't seems to care...